# Getting the error "getopt.h:85:29: fatal error: getopt-pfx-core.h: No such file or directory" while trying to compile libvirt

Tags: compiling, libvirt

In trying to compile an old version of libvirt (to see if I can get some old patches up to date, see https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2014-March/msg00106.html), I get the error:

getopt.h:85:29: fatal error: getopt-pfx-core.h: No such file or directory

when I run make (after running ./autogen.sh).

This is on libvirt commit aa50a5c.

In searching for this error ("fatal error: getopt-pfx-core.h: No such file or directory") I find very few results, but it does not seem specific to libvirt, which makes sense since the error seems to be something with getopt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are building with a clean tree.

In this case, I had files from a build of a much newer commit.

Running:

(warning, this deletes stuff in the working tree that is not in git!)

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -fdx
git clean -fdX
```

and then doing the build again worked.